# azure logic app for failed connections and slow running queries

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-sql-database, azure-logic-apps, azure-logic-app-standard

can anyone suggest how to  create the logic app for failed connections in azure to send mail automatically, diagnostics setting in logs log analytics enabled, for failed connection need how many failed connections with username and ip address.

```
AzureDiagnostics

| where event_class_s == "connection_log"

and event_subclass_s == "DISCONNECT"
```

also need to automate through logic app for slow running queries in mysql server any suggestions.

Comment: Please consider viewing the following URL - https://www.percona.com/blog/2012/12/28/auditing-login-attempts-in-mysql/ - for some ideas on how to begin achieving your goal of dealing with failed connections.

Comment: This is  from mysql server how can i run it from azure level and get the result, Diagnostic settings already enabled

Comment: what have you tried / search so far ? you probably want to create an alert that will trigger the logic app ? or having a time trigger running x minutes ?

Comment: yes from mail  alert we should get long running queries mysql, and failed connections from logic app

Comment: Please post last 100 TEXT lines from your error log for us to review your 'failed connections', please.  And post last 100 TEXT lines from your Slow Query Log, please.

Comment: What is your actual issue? you dont know how to write the KUSTO query or you dont know how to write the logic app or both?

Comment: Logic app how to configure and send mail automatically